# What is the symbol to differentiate between 3D and 4D tensors?

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus, conventions, notation

I am writing a computer program and in there I need to differentiate 3D tensors (metric tensor, Riemann tensor, Ricci scalar, Christoffel Symbols, etc.) from 4D ones.

I wanted to write something like ${g^{3}_{tt}}$, but this does not work for Riemann Tensor or Christoffel Symbols. Is there a convention for this type of thing?

Comment: The Ricci scalar is as it's name states, a scalar and has no dimensionality. The metric tensors dimensionality depends upon the space it describes and thus tensors depending on it follow suit. So you can have metric tensors of varilying dimensionality.

Comment: The indices tend to be Roman from $i$ onwards for $3$ dimensions, or either Greek or Roman from $a$ onwards for $4$ dimensions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is common to indicate the spacetime dimension $d$ of the geometry with a pre-superscript $(d)$ on tensors, e.g. $^{(3)}T$ and $^{(4)}T$, and so forth.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Btw, I think it's a great tool and anyone interested check my github repo: https://github.com/seVenVo1d/grtc_gui